# With anydice.com, how can I get the middle 5 from a roll of 7d4?

Tags: anydice

I want to roll 7d4, and drop the highest and the lowest results.

I know I can get the second highest with `output 2@7d4`, so I thought it would be something like `output 2..6@7d4` but that isn't recognized.

How can I get the sum of the middle 5 from a roll of 7d4?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You almost had it. The [correct syntax](https://anydice.com/program/2e4d1) is:

```
output {2..6}@7d4
```

Also, reading the documentation can often be helpful.  The link is in the sidebar on the left side of the AnyDice site.  You'll find this particular syntax under Documentation → Introspection → Accessing, which describes the `@` operator.

(Unfortunately, with the way the AnyDice site is implemented, I can't really link to the relevant documentation page directly.  I mean, [technically I can](https://anydice.com/documentation/introspection.html), kind of, but none of the navigation works.)

Comment: A more natural-language--if strictly less versatile--alternative is `[middle 5 of 7d4]`.